# Recurring recruiter contact on LinkedIn

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, germany, linkedin

I'm aware of quite a few questions asking about the best way to handle messages on LinkedIn from recruiters, but I think this is different enough to warrant a question of its own.

There are quite a few recruiters who send me messages about vacancies, or telling me how they are interested in my CV, or asking me how I'm feeling at my current job very often. Some of them send me messages every two weeks, every month, some more often.

Due to me being quite happy in my current job, I'm not interested in pursuing new opportunities, thus my current response is something along the lines of:

> Hey X,
>
> Thanks for contacting me. Currently I'm not interested in new job opportunities but I'll let you know when the situation changes.
>
> Greetings,
>
> Me

**Question**

Taking into account that (1) I don't plan on changing jobs in the next few months, maybe years, and (2) I don't want to burn bridges with recruiters in my area, should I even bother replying? Or are these automated messages sent to the recruiter's network or potential candidates in the area and the recruiters don't care about negative answers? If I do need to respond, I send always the same message.

**Update:** most the messages are about vacancies that are a good fit for my tech stack. If I weren't happy with my job I would most likely be interested in most of these messages. Moreover, most of them don't seem to be some spam sent to dozens of random developers in the area. The problem isn't that the jobs aren't a good for me. The issue is that the messages are too frequent.

Comment: @rkeet because I don't want to burn bridges by being unprofessional, as stated in my question.

Comment: @rkeet I get your point. But that's why I asked this questions. Are these personal messages or spam sent to everyone that matches a given criteria?

Comment: @rkeet in my case most recruiters send me messages about vacancies that are a good fit for my tech stack. Some of these (most of them, actually) don't seem to be some automatic spam that gets sent to dozens of people. I've already been in your situation and I don't reply if the vacancy is obviously not a good fit for me.

Comment: Aight, removed prev comments cause no longer relevant with that (edited in) information ;) In that case would go most of the answers that are already posted (apart from the bot automated bit ;_) ). But seriously: not answering recuitment messages does not burn bridges. It's their job, so you're absolutely in their right to not help them do their job (you have your own after all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to bother replying as they are just spam style messages hoping to catch someone at the right time. Sending your messages every two weeks is excessive and rude considering you've already made your position clear so there is no way they are expecting someone to reply each and every time. You don't need to worry about burning bridges with them since they are paid commission for each position they fill so if and when you want to switch jobs get in contact with them and they will happily put your CV forward for any openings they have available.

Answer (score 1):

I think some/most of these messages come from bots.  If you said "yes" then it would be forwarded to it's human master.

Humans would probably realize it's bad style to spam people like this.  Alternatively their list of people they contact could be VERY large.

In any case you're not burning bridges by not responding to them.  If anything you're wasting their time by saying "no" because it's something they need to read.

If you ever do go on the market then they're looking at a potential payday if they get you a job, so a history of ignoring their spam would be totally forgiven.